# How to remove extra points on graph

Tags: r

I have written the following R function:

```
#initialprob <- c(0.4,0.5,0.1)
f1 <- function(n,m,priceinitial,delta,mean, sd, ninterval){
  initialprob <- c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3)
  traders <- vector(mode="character", length=n)
  traderscurrent <- vector(mode="character", length=n)
  price <- vector(mode="numeric")
  pricecurrent <- vector(mode="numeric")

  for(nint in 1:ninterval)
  {
    print(initialprob)
    L = floor(rnorm(1,mean,sd))
    print(L)
    for(i in 1:n)
    {
      traders[i] = sample(c("B", "S", "N"), size=1, prob=initialprob)  
    }
    print(table(traders))
    for(step in 1:L)
    {

      for(i in 1:n)
      {
        b <- sample(traders[-i], m)
        #print(b)
        #table(b)
        traderscurrent[i] <- sample(b,1)

      }
      print(table(traderscurrent))
      buy = length(which(traderscurrent == "B"))
      sell = length(which(traderscurrent == "S"))
      neutral = length(which(traderscurrent == "N"))
      total = buy+neutral+sell
      buyprop = buy/total
      sellprop = sell/total
      neutralprop = neutral/total
      pricecurrent[step] = priceinitial+buy*delta-sell*delta
      priceinitial = pricecurrent[step]
      traders <- traderscurrent
      #print(nint)
      #print
    initialprob <- c(sellprop,buyprop,neutralprop)
    print(initialprob)
    }
    a <- runif(1,0,1)
    b <- runif(1,0,1)
    c <- runif(1,0,1)
    total = a+b+c
    initialprob <- c(a/total, b/total, c/total)
    print(initialprob)
    price <- append(price,pricecurrent, after=length(price))
    #price <- price[-step]
    plot(price)

  }
  print(price)
  #plot(price)

}
```

When I call  `f1(1000,100,100,10,10,1,100)`  I get a graph that looks like this:[image]

How would I fix this? It seems that there is a problem with appending the prices with previous prices. Maybe the last price of the previous iteration is being added twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the pricecurrent vector is not being reset after each iteration. Try adding `pricecurrent <- vector(mode="numeric")` just after the first `for` loop declaration:

```
for(nint in 1:ninterval)
{
  pricecurrent <- vector(mode="numeric") ## <- added
  print(initialprob)
  L = floor(rnorm(1,mean,sd))
  print(L)
  for(i in 1:n)
  ....
```