# Exporting multiple graphs in R to one file

Tags: r

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699801/how-to-remove-extra-points-on-graph), I wrote about a function  `f1 <- function(n,m,priceinitial,delta,mean, sd, ninterval)`  that plots prices based on various rules. I have added the following code:

```
f2 <- function(nsim){
  for(i in 1:nsim)
  {
    f1(1000,100,100,10,10,1,100)
  }
}
```

Basically I want to repeat the same experiment multiple times and save the all of the graphs in one single file. How would I do this?

Comment: you could save them as PDF e.g.: pdf("my_plots.pdf", onefile = TRUE)

Comment: If you want the plots in a `pdf`, `doc` or `html` file, consider using [RMarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/). If you want the graphs side by side on the same image you can use 'facets_grid` option of `ggplot`.

Comment: @ed_sans: So I would add that to that after my plot statement in my <code> f1 </code> function?

Comment: @Damien , you could call it before e.g: pdf("my_plots.pdf", onefile = TRUE);
for (i in n) {p <- plot()); print(p)}.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that you can do is collect all of the outputs in one plot variable and export that as a single file, otherwise, you would keep writing over the same file over and over again.

```
jpeg(filename = "plot1.jpeg", width = 2000, height = 2000)
par(mfrow = c(nsim, 1))
f2(nsim)
dev.off()
```